# Javascript - how to add new div dynamically and append data to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I am working at basically example of SignalR - here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SignalR Simple Chat</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            background-color: #99CCFF;
            border: thick solid #808080;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>

    <style type="text/css">
        .box {
            background-color: #0000ff;
            border: thick solid #008000;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="message"/>
    <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
</div>

<div class="box" id="box1">
</div>


<!--Script references. -->
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" "></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                // Html encode display name and message.
                var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
                // Add the message to the page.    
                $('#box1').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                    + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
            };
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub.
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here above:

```
$('#box1').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                    + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
```

Some data is added to my div, it is a rectangle with borders, and every time when I write sth to textbox, a new data is displayed, and rectangle is getting bigger, but I want to display new div(rectangle) above one every time when I write a new text. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

i think your code is right but you have to check whether written text is previously appende or not to the div.if it is already then you have to do nothing but if it not there then append your text to the div.

Comment: It's not about that. Append works, but then my box is getting bigger. I want to add new box every time, when I write new text and clicked 'send'

Comment: you have to use  .insertAfter() to insert new box. http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/